# Dismiss WatchKit Modal Segue to Root Controller

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, segue, watchkit

I am creating an watchOS app where there is a Interface Controller (Interface Controller 1) that has a button. That button has a modal segue to Interface Controller 2 and Interface Controller 2 has a button that has a modal segue to Interface Controller 3. Whenever the user clicks the cancel button on Interface Controller 3, it takes them to Interface Controller 2. But, I want it to take them to Interface Controller 1. How do I do this? Here's the diagram: [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to go to root view controller.

```
popToRootController()
```

Call the above method to go to root view controller from your action method in 3rd interface.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of is to communicate back to Interface Controller 1 somehow (a notification?) and let it use the method:

`self.becomeCurrentPage()`

e.g.

```
@IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.CancelSelected, object: self)
}
```

and then in Interface Controller 1:

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.CancelSelected, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
        self.becomeCurrentPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: `becomeCurrentPage()` isn't supposed to dismiss modals.

Comment: Does the doc actually state this?  Even if your solution, to call dismiss() does indeed work, you still need the notification or similar to communicate the need to dismiss from the nested controller to the root controller.

Comment: I tested the solution described in my answer practice.

Comment: That's good that it works.  I've not had time to try it myself.  But saying that, the solution I've posted above also works.  next time I update the app I will investigate your solution in case it provides an improved UX.

Comment: You are so serious about correctness of your answers, we all appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

For me calling `dismiss()` on the root controller worked. On some other controller than root the call will look like this:

```
WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController?.dismiss()
```

This will dismiss any number of modals, while calling `dismiss()` on a modal will dismiss it and those presented from it.